# Confused about the meaning of calculating sum in Pandas Pivot Table

Tags: python, pandas

```
pd.pivot_table(df1,index=['Staff'],columns=['Products'],values=['Price'],margins=True)
```

Results:

```
Price
Products    A                 B              C              All
Staff                   
Staff_A 14472.000000    15877.777778    14982.352941    14890.196078
Staff_B 14775.000000    15620.000000    16330.000000    15815.789474
Staff_C 15293.333333    14262.500000    15214.285714    15000.000000
All     14779.545455    15231.818182    15426.470588    15099.000000
```

The result can be shown successfully, however I do not understand where the values from the column and row `All` come from. Can anyone explain where the value of sum comes from, because I thought it should be the sum of the first three columns data added together?

Comment: I think you need to supply `aggfunc=np.sum` for the pivot to take the sum.

Comment: So what is the meaning if I only used ```margins=True``` ? I still do not understand the values origin

Comment: `margins=True` will add column total and row total using default `aggfunc`, that is `mean`.

Comment: So I do not understand where is the column total and row total? I am being confused with that so better show an example

Comment: I mean the last row values ```14779.545455,15231.818182,15426.470588,15099.000000``` that although I added up the corresponding columns then divided by 3 is not the result that I expect

Comment: Yea, i noticed that, too. Illustration provided below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Create dummy dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'id': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
  'stat': ['col1', 'col1', 'col1', 'col2', 'col2', 'col2'],
  'val': [2, 4, 6, 6, 8, 10],
})
```

This will give us:

```
>>> df
    id  stat    val
0   a   col1    2
1   b   col1    4
2   c   col1    6
3   a   col2    6
4   b   col2    8
5   c   col2    10
```

Pivoting without giving `aggfunc` argument

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index='id', columns='stat', values='val', margins=True)
```

The above will give us:

```
>>> table
stat    col1    col2    All
id          
a       2       6       4.0
b       4       8       6.0
c       6       10      8.0
All     4       8       6.0
```

Notice that column All and row All both giving us the mean of the columns and rows, respectively.

Pivoting and using `aggfunc=np.sum`:

```
new_table = pd.pivot_table(df, index='id', columns='stat', values='val', margins=True, aggfunc=np.sum)
```

This will give us:

```
>>> new_table
stat    col1    col2    All
id          
a       2       6       8
b       4       8       12
c       6       10      16
All     12      24      36
```

Comment: so if I didn't add ```aggfunc=np.sum``` what the result in ```All``` meaning?

Comment: I believe `All` in `margins` will use default `aggfunc` which is mean. [See here for further info](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

Comment: so is the mean calculated by the sum divided by the total number of data?